# Show python logging color in vs code debug consol

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, odoo

I'm trying to change the color of logging in the debug console. But every vs code is interpreting logging.info as error and only getting the color of error.
Here is my setting

```
        "debugConsole.infoForeground": "#ffffff",
        "debugConsole.warningForeground": "#fddf00",
        "debugConsole.errorForeground": "#69ba63",
        "debugConsole.sourceForeground": "#c2c900",
```

And here is the log I got

[image]

As in the picture, you can see my log level is info, but vscode shows errorForeground color.

My example:

```
import logging
_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    _logger.warning('Test warning')
    _logger.error('Test error')
```

My launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "internalConsole",
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

[image: result]

How can vscode display colors according to logging levels?

Comment: This question would benefit from a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For example, what tools are you using for logging?

Comment: Please edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

> The Debug Console is a generic VSCode facility that is not aware of the Python logging module, and vice versa. Logging output ends up in Debug Console because it goes to stderr by default, and everything in stderr is captured in the console. However, there's no way to know whether the message was logged as "warning" or "error" at this point.

You can keep track of this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/issues/1161#).